# Django - Start Session by Ajax Request

Tags: ajax, django, django-authentication, django-login

I need to know how to start a session by Ajax in Django. I'm doing exactly as described bellow, but it is not working! The request is sent correctly, but don't start any session. If a request directly without ajax it works! What is going on?

**'# urls**

```
r'^logout/$', 'autenticacao.views.logout_view'
```

'**# view of login**

```
def login_view(request):

    username = request.GET.get('username', '')
    password = request.GET.get('password', '')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse(user.get_profile().sos_user.name)            
    return HttpResponse('user invalido')
```

**'# ajax in a html page**

```
$(function(){

 $.get('http://localhost:8000/logout/?username=usuario?>&password=senha', function(data){
   alert(data);
 });
```

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Thanks for cleaning that up, the issue jumped right out at me as soon as it was formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the `login_view`.  You're ajax request is going to the `/logout/` url which is calling the `autenticacao.views.logout_view`.

Also, The `?>` after `username=usuario` doesn't look right in the your get url.

My guess is you should be doing something like `http://localhost:8000/login/?username=usuario&password=senha`. (but I'd need to see your login url mapping to be sure).

Also, you should be `POST`ing the login information and using `HTTPS` for security reasons, but that's a different issue.

Comment: sorry, the url correct is : r'^login/$', 'autenticacao.views.login_view' but it instill does not work yet!

Comment: Can you see that you're successfully logging in?  Try adding adding `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` after `login(request, user)`, or even just `raise` an exception.